# Adding a JComponent on top (z order) of the component in border layout

Tags: java, swing, z-index, z-order, border-layout

Border layout has been really popular as it stretches it's contents to fit the parent component. And so I have some JComponent that is laid out with `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and I need to show another JComponent a top of it. As some sort of properties window or something. Is there any common way to do it or should I rebuild the whole app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) Component.

Answer (score 4):

> I have some JComponent that is laid out with BorderLayout.CENTER, and I need to show another JComponent a top of it

1. there are two (three ways)

   - use `GlassPane`
   - use `JLayer (Java7)`, based on `JXLayer (Java6)`
   - use `JViewport` (not `Component` not `Container`) in the case the is there some (required figure for `Swing GUI` is `JFrame` - `JScrollPane` - `JPanel`)
2. use `CardLayout` for `JFrames CENTER` area
3. (shot to the dark) call `(re)validate` and `repaint()` to nearest `Container` as last code line in current code block for switching betweens `JPanels` views

EDIT

you can to use [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm) too

Comment: Can I add a `JComponent` to `GlassPane`?

Comment: `1)` yes no issue, `2)` but GlassPane has not implemented any `LayoutManager`, don't to use `AbsoluteLayout`...e.g. `setBounds`, `setSize`, `3)` you can to overloay required `Rectangle` or to stick over desired `JComponent`, `4)` notice, `GlassPane` to `consume() MouseEvenst` only, you have to `consume()` programatically events that came from `keyboard`

Comment: You can set the glass pane to use a `LayoutManager`, but in this context, it's probably not recommended. Don't forget to set the glass pane to `visible` ;)